# Use URL scheme to open react-native App

Tags: ios, authentication, react-native, spotify

I am working on a **react-native** app that uses the **Spotify** api.
Long story short, I had to use the **LiknkingIOS** Library to open the auth page in the Safari app and get the necessary tokens and all works, I even got to redirect to my app one the user is successfully authenticated using a **custom URL scheme**.

**The only problem** is that a prompt saying *"Open in 'myApp'?"* appears.

I need help figuring out a way to avoid the prompt from appearing or using another component to open Spotify's auth page without leaving the app.

Comment: I have the same issue, did you ever manage to figure it out @Andres C. Viesca?

Comment: Any luck with this? Having the same issue